# Completar cajas de texto con angular

Tags: javascript, angular, spring

Soy nuevo con Angular y quisiera saber si se puede realizar lo siguiente:

Tengo las siguientes cajas de texto: Código postal, Ciudad, Delegación/Municipio y Estado; quiero autocompletar las últimas tres de acuerdo al código postal que fue ingresado, aún no encuentro alguna información que me ayude.

El código postal lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-zip-code">Código Postal:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-zip-code" name="txt-zip-code" maxlength="5" minlength="5" ng-model="info.zipCode" required="required" dig its="digits">
</div>
```

Tengo un servicio en el cual al introducir un código postal valido te muestra la información como delegación/municipio, ciudad, estado e incluso las colonias con ese código postal, ahora como puedo hacer para que apunte a mi servicio y de acuerdo al código postal que yo meta me cargue los demás campos.

Anexo los demás campos:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-city">Ciudad:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-city" name="txt-city" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.city" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-municipality">Delegación/Municipio:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-municipality" name="txt-municipality" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.municipality" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-state">Estado:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-state" name="txt-state" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.state" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
</div>
```

Mi servicio esta hecho con spring y es tipo Rest que devuelve un objeto con los campos estado, delegación/municipio, colonias.

Espero haberme explicado.

Update 1
Consumo mi servicio de la siguiente manera, en mi archivo configurationService:

```
   getDataZipCode: function(zipcode) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/configurator/rest/getZipCode?zipcode=' + zipcode
        });
    },
```

Como pueden ver es un servicio GET que obtiene los datos antes mencionados.
Ahora para obtener los datos(según yo) lo hago de la siguiente manera, en mi archivo onlineController.js :

```
Service.getDataZipCode().then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.getDataZipCode = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(responseError) {
        growl.error("Error al recuperar los datos del codigo postal", {ttl:5000});
    });
```

Ahora como hago para que se llenen los campos de ciudad, delegación/municipio y estado al momento en que el usuario introduce un código postal?

Gracias.

Comment: En particular que tienes duda. ¿Cómo realizar la petición? ¿Cómo llenar esos campos con la información recuperada?

Comment: Así es, cómo puedo realizar eso

Comment: @AngelOropeza actualice mi pregunta, espero me haya explicado lo que realmente quiero hacer

Comment: Te recomiendo que comiences con las nuevas versiones de Angular(2x), esto para que veas que ciertas propiedades han cambiado de una forma radical a la tradicional en cuanto al desarrollo de aplicaciones (Móviles o web) con Angular, además de ser mucho más potente. Y ten en cuenta que tu etiqueta es una versión diferente (AngularJS) a la que expresaste (Angular)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día colega! Espero que este ejemplo te pueda ayudar. Lo que debes tener en cuenta es:
1 - Los inputs deben tener ng-models que puedas manipular en tu controlador
2 - Distribuir adecuadamente las propiedades del objeto que obtienes como respuesta de tu servicio.

Observa este ejemplo y trata de adaptarlo a tu necesidad.
Coloca en el input un numero y dale search del 1 - 10 para obtener una respuesta correcta.

```html
<!doctype html >
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="UserController as user">
    <form ng-submit="user.getUser();">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.userId">
        <button type="submit">Search user</button>

        <input type="text" ng-model="user.chosenUser.name">
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.chosenUser.email">
    </form>
    <pre>{{ user.chosenUser | json }}</pre>
</div>

<script>
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('UserController', function (UserService) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.userId = '';
            ctrl.chosenUser = {};
            ctrl.getUser = function () {
                if (!ctrl.userId) {
                    return;
                }
                UserService
                    .getUser(ctrl.userId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        ctrl.chosenUser = response;
                    });
            }
        })
        .service('UserService', function ($http) {
            var API = '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/';

            this.getUser = function (userId) {
                return $http
                    .get(API + userId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }, function (reason) {
                        return reason;
                    });
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, en cuanto lo adecue y prueba te digo que tal me fue, pero parece ser exactamente lo que busco. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu servicio cuando ya llega la llama correcta al consumir la api actualiza el modelo

```javascript
Service.getDataZipCode().then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.getDataZipCode = response.data;
        //acá actualiza tu modelo llamado info

        $scope.info.city = response.data.city

        // y así para el resto de tus campos 


    }, function errorCallback(responseError) {
        growl.error("Error al recuperar los datos del codigo postal", {ttl:5000});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar los datos de la respuesta de alguna interfaz de aplicacion, por ejemplo si usas [Zipcodebase](https://app.zipcodebase.com) con esta url de peticion `https://app.zipcodebase.com/api/v1/search?apikey=apiKey&codes=5374` obtendras algo como esto:

```
{
  "query": {"codes":["5374"],"country":null},
  "results":
    {
    "5374":
      [{"postal_code":"5374", 
      "country_code":"NL",
      "latitude":"51.74320000",
      "longitude":"5.63300000",
      "city":"Schaijk",
      "state":"Noord-Brabant",
      "city_en":"Schaijk",
      "state_en":"Noord-Brabant", 
      "state_code":"06",
      "province":"Landerd",
      "province_code":"1685"}]
    }
}
```

entonces en tu componente principal (donde haces la peticion `http.get`)

```
Service.getDataZipCode().then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.getDataZipCode = response.data;
    $scope.info.city = response.data.results.city;
    $scope.info.municipality = response.data.results.province;
    $scope.info.state = response.data.results.state;
}, function errorCallback(responseError) {
    growl.error("Error al recuperar los datos del codigo postal", {ttl:5000});
});
```

En caso de usar `<form>` podrías usar algo como esto

```
<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.info.city = response.data.results.city;
      $scope.info.municipality = response.data.results.province;
      $scope.info.state = response.data.results.state;
    }]);
</script>
```

Creo que esos ejemplos podrian servirte para mostrar los datos recibidos en los elementos del formulario que contiene `ng-controller="FormController"` de esta manera

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="FormController">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-city">Ciudad:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-city" name="txt-city" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.city" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-municipality">Delegación/Municipio:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-municipality" name="txt-municipality" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.municipality" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label for="txt-state">Estado:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txt-state" name="txt-state" maxlength="40" ng-model="info.state" required="required" onlyspaces="false">
  </div>
</form>
```